# Why don't bound params work in an IN statement?

Tags: resource-model, php-pdo

In my custom resource model, I'm trying to use `fetchAssoc` to get some data from a table. I'm trying to quote an array into an IN statement, and I've noticed that it doesn't work (returns an empty array) when using named bindings. However, using the second argument of `$select->where()` to quote the values in works fine.

I'm just curious why this doesn't work...

```
$bind = array( 
    'expert_id' => $expert_id,
    'product_id' => $adapter->quote($product_id),
);

//Debug:  Array ( [expert_id] => 1, [product_id] => '3032', '3091', '3132' )

$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from($this->getTable('namespace_module/table'), '*')
    ->where('product_id IN(:product_id)')
    ->where('expert_id = :expert_id');

// Debug: SELECT `namespace_module_table`.* FROM `namespace_module_table` WHERE (product_id IN('3032', '3091', '3132')) AND (expert_id = :expert_id)
```

but this does?

```
$bind = array( 
    'expert_id' => $expert_id,
);

//Debug: Array(  [expert_id] => 1 )

$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from($this->getTable('namespace_module/table'), '*')
    ->where('product_id IN(?)', $product_id)
    ->where('expert_id = :expert_id');

// Debug: SELECT `namespace_module_table`.* FROM `namespace_module_table` WHERE (product_id IN(:product_id)) AND (expert_id = :expert_id)
```

Is it a general rule that you can't use bound params in an IN statement? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition), but I thought Magento's `$adapter->quote` method was supposed to take care of turning the array into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento, and most modern PHP database abstractions, ultimately rely on the PDO library's bound parameter implementation for bound parameter support.  [PDO doesn't support binding array to an IN parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) for -- reasons?  It's been that way as long as I've been using the library, and is super annoying.

To work around this, many PHP database abstractions offer `IN` support for their own, *unbound* parameters.   In the second code example Magento's underlying SQL abstraction libraries are generating an `IN` statement for you with hard coded values from the array, and then sending that to the database.  This is different from using a bound parameter -- with a bound parameter your'e sending a SQL statement with that bound parameter to the database, and also telling the database which variables apply to which parameters.